# laravel validate radio array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I use laravel 5.3, this my snippet view code :

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[1]" type="radio" value="1" >Rate 1</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[1]" type="radio" value="2" >Rate 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[2]" type="radio" value="1" >Rate 1</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[2]" type="radio" value="2" >Rate 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and this my validation in controller :

```
$rules = array(
     'val[]'    => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5',
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

If I check all radio and submit form, the error appears with this message : The val[] field is required.

How to validate array of radios ?

**Update this solution**

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[1]" type="radio" value="1" required="true" >Rate 1</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[1]" type="radio" value="2" required="true" >Rate 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[2]" type="radio" value="1" required="true" >Rate 1</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input name="val[2]" type="radio" value="2" required="true" >Rate 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

thank to answerers this question

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as:

```
$rules = array(
     'val'    => 'required|array',
     'val.*'    => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5',
);
```

Comment: If I use this 'val.*'    => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5', when radio button doesn't checked, its no validation, its pass condition

Comment: thank for your update, Now, if I just check one radio, its pass condition

Comment: Its because if a radio button is not checked then it's not passed to the server. You have to make sure that the data is passed to the server. There can be two workaround - one is use `required` attribute of HTML or by making the radio buttons checked by default.

Comment: thank @Amit Gupta , this is my solution, 
<input name="val[1]" type="radio" value="1" required="true" >Rate 1</label>

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
$rules = array(
   'val'    => 'required|array',
   'val.*'    => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5',
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I change my code to your advice code, but doesn't work, its no validation if I dont check all radio

Comment: thank, for your update, the result of your advice,, if I check one radio its as pass condition

Comment: not yet,, the correct condition is if 2 radios in 2 rows was checked its pass condition for validator